# memory warnings and crash with no info from instruments or xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm runnning an IOS Cocos2D app that shows about 6 mb allocated on the memory leaks tool.  After I repeatedly change scenes a bit, I accrue 2 or 3 memory warnings, then BOOM, I get the axe.  The weird thing is, instruments shows no leak, no zombies (enabled) say anything, the output window is unremarkable.  Nothing, except . . . instruments always freezes.

Any ideas of what would cause this type behavior?

Comment: What are the "2 or 3 memory warnings" you get? Can you add logging to your code to determine which function was the last one called? That might help you narrow it down.

Comment: Also, there is a difference between leaked memory (memory which you've allocated and then lost the pointers to, so you can't release them) and poor memory management (Using memory inefficiently)

Comment: "received memory warning."; I added logging to some functions but I guess I may have to add nslogs to every one soon, since I cant seem to pin it down.

Comment: If you keep allocating memory, but hardly release it, then you don't have a leak, but you are being wasteful with your memory usage. Which you can see as you are getting memory warnings.

Comment: @Abizern: But would that not show up on instruments as allocated memory?  As stated, instruments shows about 6 mb allocated, with a peak of around 10-12 mb but returning back to around 6.  The crashes appear to occur at less than 8 mb.

Comment: What is the sampling rate for your allocations? If you are suddenly using a lot of memory you'll crash your app before you see the change reflected in instruments.

Comment: Sampling rate?  Never heard of it.  How do I check that?

Comment: Recommend watching WWDC 2010 Session 311 Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments

Comment: Is their any way, other than nslog, to identify which line (or approximately") occurs just before the crash?

Comment: The instruments allocation tool...

Comment: @CodaFi: instruments freezes without fail when the crash occurs.